# Unable to Run Query, dbo.tablename invalid object name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamicquery

I am trying to build a dynamic query that will insert or update a record based on row exists in db, if yes i will update a bunch of records & sub records depending on @ObjectID.

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @ObjectID BIGINT = 0;
SET @ObjectID = 0;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID 
               FROM dbo.ResortInfo 
               WHERE dbo.ResortInfo.resortCode = N'PYI')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.ResortInfo (columns) 
    VALUES (colvalues)

    SET @ObjectID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    PRINT @ObjectID
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Already exists' -- update query will replace here
END
```

The query runs ok without the declare part, but when I add

```
DECLARE @ObjectID BIGINT = 0;
SET @ObjectID = 0;
```

I get the following error :

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.ResortInfo'

Comment: That usually means that you don't actually have a table named `dbo.ResortInfo`.

Comment: You should get the same error if you run `select * from dbo.ResortInfo`

Comment: after both your comments, i checked the SSMS again and the db master was selected in query runner now i feels like a fool

Comment: and here i was headbutting with this issue since last 4 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would double check that you have the correct db selected. I currently have master selected, but your table may live in another.

[image: db_catalog]

In your stored procedure you could add this at the top to ensure you are using the correct one.

```
USE [<your db name here>]
```

Comment: yup, that was it i  didnt noticed it when i was using the new query button from live db it defaulted to master database lol